# сменить версию проекта

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core, visual-studio-2019

есть проект Worker Service версия которого **netcoreapp3.1** хочу снизить версию до **.NET Framework 4.5** и в вошел properties/application и в Target framework не видно .NET Framework 4.5 там только .Net Core 3.1, 3.0, 2.2, 2.1, 2.0, 1.1, 1.0 и Net 5, потом скачал .NET Framework 4.5 Developer Pack установил перезапустил VS 2019 сделал рестарт компиутера,но все равно в properties/application и в Target framework не видно .NET Framework 4.5,
что делать?

Answer (score 0):

.NET Framework и .NET Core - разные платформы разработки и несовместимы между собой, поэтому Visual Studio не предоставляет возможности перенести проект на другую платформу. Единственный способ, который я знаю - создать новый проект на требуемой платформе и перенести в него кодовую базу из старого. Что, как правило, сопровождается болью. Если нет строгой потребности именно в этой уже сильно устаревшей версии .NET Framework, рекомендовал бы по возможности поднимать платформу проекта до .NET 5.